# Compute the max of 2 operands whose evaluation may causes side effects, in preprocessing

Tags: c, max, c-preprocessor, side-effects

I found myself in need of computing the maximal value of 2 operands.

- The 2 operands may have side effects and must be evaluated only once, and
- The evaluation take place in preprocessing macro, and allocation of additional variable is not preferred (although if viable, it's allowed).

The best solution I've come up so far is to `bit-or` them together, which has smaller overhead than arithmetic addition. Even though this doesn't get the maximal value of the 2 operands, it tells a value that's big enough to hold working context of either size.

```
typedef struct {
    void (*initfunc)(void *restrict x);
    void (*updatefunc)(void *restrict x, const void *restrict in, size_t len);
    void (*finalfunc)(void *restrict x, void *restrict out);
} hash_funcs_set;

typedef struct {
    unsigned            hlen_msg;
    unsigned            hlen_mgf;
    hash_funcs_set_t    hfuncs_msg, hfuncs_mgf;
} pkcs1_padding_oracles_base_t;

#define PKCS1_PADDING_ORACLES_T(...)            \
    struct {                                    \
        pkcs1_padding_oracles_base_t base;      \
        uint8_t hashctx[__VA_ARGS__];           \
    }

typedef PKCS1_PADDING_ORACLES_T() pkcs1_padding_oracles_t;

#define PKCS1_PADDING_ORACLES_CTX_SIZE_X(hmsg, hmgf) (  \
        sizeof(pkcs1_padding_oracles_base_t) +          \
        (CTX_BYTES(hmsg) | CTX_BYTES(hmgf)) )

// CTX_BYTES is a function-like macro that invokes hmsg (which
// can be either another function-like expression macro, or a 
// function pointer), to obtain the size of hash function working 
// context size.
```

```
// Possible definitions of a hmsg/hmgf:
#define macro_SHA256(q) (\
        q==1 ? 32 /* output bytes */ : \
        q==2 ? 256 /* size of working variable set */ : \
        q==3 ? (intptr_t)SHA256_Init : \
        q==4 ? (intptr_t)SHA256_Update : \
        q==5 ? (intptr_t)SHA256_Final : \
        0)

intptr_t info_SHA256(int q) { return macro_SHA256(q); }
...
#define OUT_BYTES(obj) (obj(1))
#define CTX_BYTES(obj) (obj(2))
...
```

The reason I deem this acceptable is because I'm actually allocating memory working contexts for a data structure union (therefore integers) which may be used by 2 different set of functions at different times without conflict, and I hope some XY problem can be spotted and better solution can be devised.

I expect `PKCS1_PADDING_ORACLES_CTX_SIZE_X(hmsg,hmgf)` expands to constant expression when `hmsg` and `hmgf` are constant expressions, but they can be anything and may cause side effects.

The language is standard C, any version. Compiler-specific features are not preferred.

Comment: "*The best solution I've come up*". There are a few unclear points in the question. Please show that attempted solution to make the question clearer.

Comment: @kaylum I've included a code fragment to demonstrate how I intend to calculate working context size.

Comment: `CTX_BYTES(hmsg) | CTX_BYTES(hmgf)` How does that get the max? For example, if one operand is 4 and the other is 8 the result will be 12.

Comment: @kaylum edited the paragraph just preceeding the code fragment.

Comment: I do not understand. `The 2 operands have side effects` Ergo they can't be calculated in preprocessor, they are not constant.

Comment: @KamilCuk Strictly speaking, they're calculated in the expression expanded from the preprocessing macro definition.

Comment: Please try to simplify your example more, and extend it to a [example], even if it has side-effects. I don't get the goal you try to reach.

Comment: "when hsmg and hmgf are constant expressions, but they can be anything and may cause side effects." This does not really go together well for me.

Comment: Is this a practical problem, or a puzzle you have been set, or a puzzle you have set yourself?

Comment: @SteveSummit One I set myself. I've already had the partial solution of using bitwise-or, I'm just not sure if anybody has a better way.

Answer (score 1):

> The 2 operands have side effects

That means they are not constant expressions. So just write a function to calculate the max. With proper type.

```
// hash_ret_type - the return type of hash function.
// Or it's just unsigned long long or uintmax_t, if super lazy.

hash_ret_type hash_max(hash_ret_type a, hash_ret_type b) {
     return a > b ? a : b;
}

#define PKCS1_PADDING_ORACLES_CTX_SIZE_X(hmsg, hmgf) (  \
        sizeof(pkcs1_padding_oracles_base_t) +          \
        hash_max(CTX_BYTES(hmsg), CTX_BYTES(hmgf)) )
```

If you are interested in using GNU extensions, you might want to interest in [max() linux kernel macros](https://lwn.net/Articles/750306/).